# Magento - Who ordered what in Magento webshop with a query on db?

Tags: mysql, magento

I'm trying to figure out who orders what in our webshop so that our marketing intern can figure out what every customer is worth, etc.

I've built a query, but it doesn't seem to work correctly:

```
SELECT e.*, sfoi.*, sfoa.lastname, sfoa.email, sfoa.street, sfoa.postcode, sfoa.country_id
FROM sales_flat_order e
INNER JOIN sales_flat_order_item sfoi ON (e.entity_id=sfoi.order_id) 
INNER JOIN sales_flat_order_address sfoa ON (e.customer_id=sfoa.customer_id)
WHERE date_format(e.created_at, '%Y') LIKE '2015' 
AND sfoi.parent_item_id IS NULL 
AND sfoi.qty_ordered > 0;
```

The matching of the customer_id gives back the wrong results and I don't think I understand the database model that I found on magereverse.com thoroughly enough to figure this one out.

We are working with Magento 1.7.0.2. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

-edit- 
I think I found the solution:

```
SELECT e.*, sfoi.*, sfoa.lastname, sfoa.email, sfoa.street, sfoa.postcode, sfoa.country_id
FROM sales_flat_order e
INNER JOIN sales_flat_order_item sfoi ON (e.entity_id=sfoi.order_id) 
INNER JOIN sales_flat_order_address sfoa ON (e.entity_id=sfoa.parent_id)
WHERE date_format(e.created_at, '%Y') LIKE '2015' 
AND sfoi.parent_item_id IS NULL 
AND sfoi.qty_ordered > 0;
```

Comment: You should answer your own question, then accept your answer after that option becomes available.

Comment: Okay! Didn't know that, will update it now ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT e.*, sfoi.*, sfoa.lastname, sfoa.email, sfoa.street, sfoa.postcode,  sfoa.country_id
FROM sales_flat_order e
INNER JOIN sales_flat_order_item sfoi ON (e.entity_id=sfoi.order_id) 
INNER JOIN sales_flat_order_address sfoa ON (e.entity_id=sfoa.parent_id)
WHERE date_format(e.created_at, '%Y') LIKE '2015' 
AND sfoi.parent_item_id IS NULL 
AND sfoi.qty_ordered > 0;
```

The problem was with the matching the keys of sales_flat_order_address and sales_flat_order

Answer (score 0):

Magento 1.7.0.2 provide report filters which available under Reports menu in admin panel. It already have such report tools like:

Reports > Sales > Orders

Reports > Products > Bestsellers

Reports > Products > Products ordered

Reports > Customers > Customers by order totals

Reports > Customers > Customers by number of ordes

etc.

Comment: I know about these reports, but they don't tell you exactly what each customer individually bought and I needed all that raw data. :)